# How do I configure sshuttle to only forward specific IP addresses from another network to the client device?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, sshuttle

How would I configure sshuttle to only make certain IP addresses from the host's network available?

For example, let's say that an employee is using a VPN to connect to their corporate's network from home, and they happen to open a new browser window to search Google. Google's IP address isn't really hosted on the corporate's network. I am sure there could be security reasons or benefits as to why the employee should still be connected through the corporate VPN even to access various external addresses, but my situation is still different.

I have a robot which has a router providing a network for it's various components (a Raspberry Pi, an ESP32, ESP8266, an IP camera, etc). This router is connected to my house's main router. I have an old laptop which has Ubuntu 20 installed on it, and it is a development laptop used to mimick an external cloud instance which will act as the "brain" for my robot. This devbrain computer is connected under my house's main network.

I am able to create a tunnel to the robot's network using sshuttle, but I only want the IP addresses of the various devices that I listed above (a Raspberry Pi, an ESP32, ESP8266, an IP camera, etc) to be available on devbrain. Every other address needs to be accessed as if the VPN wasn't connected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue !

sshuttle -r user@server 192.168.0.52/16

It works for me (monip.org give me my real public IP address and when I try to open 192.168.0.52 that is in the network of server, it works)

Comment: Worked for me, too. Thank you!